# The control is not available or not valid. coded UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

when  I login to a page , verify something, logout and re-open the same page again in the same test case. in coded UI C#.?

It shows the following error. Test fails.  Any idea?

Test method : CodedUITest1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The control is not available or not valid.
```

Comment: It is not the same page. It may look the same and be derived from the same HTML, but it is a different page as it is a new rendering of the contents of the page.

Comment: You got any answer to it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that.

can you check that your keyboard lang is english? (mine was turkish and was not getting the input correctly)

is it possible to try it on VS2013. I installed ultimate edition and fixed it.

Comment: I am using VS2013 premium and my keyboard lang is english then also m getting this problem. I have solved this by using controlName.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch); but also getting this problem some time . If you have any another solution please share, Thank you .